# Call the parent function recursively in a non-blocking callback function

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback

Is it possible to call a parent function recursively in a non-blocking callback function?

For example:

```
function checkValidZip(zipInput) {
    if (!zipInput.trim().match(/^(\d{5})$/g)) {

      userInput("Please enter a valid 5 digit shipping zip code", function(zip){
        //recursively call the parent function to check for valid zip 
        //(and continue to prompt the user until they enter proper zip)
        return checkValidZip(zip);
      });

    }
    //and return (only) the valid zip
    return output(zipInput);

 }

function userInput(param1, callback){

    input = prompt(param1);
    callback(input);
}

function output(param){

   alert(param);

}
checkValidZip(prompt("hello"));
```

http://jsbin.com/omubab/1/edit

Obviously, the issue is that the code will continue to execute without waiting to call the callback function (therefore not checking the zip in this example) and the additional iterations of the recursive functions aren't called until after the parent has returned (in this example `return output(zipInput);`).

So, again, is it possible to have have a "self-calling" recursive function as a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example you can get behavior that seems reasonable just by using `else output(zipInput)` at the end of `checkValidZip`.

More generally you may want `checkValidZip` to take a callback:

```
function checkValidZip(zipInput, callback) {
    if (!zipInput.trim().match(/^(\d{5})$/g)) {

    userInput("Please enter a valid 5 digit shipping zip code", function(zip){
        //recursively call the parent function to check for valid zip 
        //(and continue to prompt the user until they enter proper zip)
        checkValidZip(zip,callback);
    });

    }
    //and return (only) the valid zip
    else callback(zipInput);
}

checkValidZip(prompt("hello"),output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not like this. You can use Promises.

```
function checkValidZip(zipInput) {
    var promise = new Promise();
    if (!zipInput.trim().match(/^(\d{5})$/g)) {
        userInput("Please enter a valid 5 digit shipping zip code", function(zip){
            checkValidZip(zip).done(function () {
                promise.resolve(zip);
            });
        });
    }
    return promise;
}

checkValidZip(prompt("hello")).done(function (zip) {
    console.log("valid zip:", zip);
}
```

Promises are not natively available, Google for a library that you like. jQuery has one too.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's so weird that this isn't native. Seems like it would be a common problem.